# Xgboost giving import error in pythonAnywhere

Tags: python, pythonanywhere, xgboost

I installed xgboost in PythonAnywhere and it shows successful but when I import it in a script, an error is given which says, "No module xgboost found". What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed it for a version of Python that is different to the one that you're running.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use Anaconda2 and installed **xgboost** through git. Everything was ok but I got this message while trying to use import xgboost:

> No module xgboost found

When I run `pip install xgboost` I got the message that everything is ok and xgboost is installed.

I went on `../Anaconda2/Lib/site-package` and saw a folder `xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg`, and inside there was other one `xgboost`. I just copied this folder `xgboost` and pasted it inside `../Anaconda2/Lib/site-package`. And now it works =)